# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
#Load dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data = load_breast_cancer
```

When I run below command

```
data.keys()
```

It shows an error like this

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 data.keys()
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: You didn't invoke the function `data = load_breast_cancer()`

Answer (score 4):

`load_breast_cancer` is a function. With:

```py
data = load_breast_cancer
```

You assign the function `load_breast_cancer` to the variable `data`, making the variable `data` refer to the function `load_breast_cancer`. If you want to get the data that the `load_breast_cancer` function returns and put it in the variable `data`, you have to call it like so:

```py
data = load_breast_cancer()
```